# Reading characters from txt file as nodes for search tree (artificial intelligence)

Tags: java

This is a search tree problem (Romania map may be taken as a refenrence). I'm trying to read chars from text file. This file has several lines and each line contains a parent-child relation (root node and child node) and a path cost between them. Example is below:

> A B 5
>   A C 3
>   B D 6

Should I use `BufferedReader` here in order to take these values and implement them into my code, or another reader should be used? If so, how can I split data char by char?

So far, I've used this code:

```
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("tree.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        //here I should import characters, split them by space 
        //and use them as a root node, child node and cost value
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Actually nodes are:

```
    Node J = new Node("J",10);
    Node K = new Node("K",3);
    Node L = new Node("L",19);
    Node M = new Node("M",5);
    Node N = new Node("N",7);
    Node O = new Node("O",8);
    Node P = new Node("P",8);
    Node Q = new Node("Q",0);

    J.setChildren(new Node[]{K,L,M});
    K.setChildren(new Node[]{N,O,P,Q});
```

Comment: You can use `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` as well for the work. Please try something and come back when you have a specific programming problem. If you have tried something with `BufferedReader`, then please edit your question and provide the relevant code to help you.

Comment: Well, seems that your problem is not about reading the data from the file but more about how to create your `Node`s and fill them with children. Probably you should have a `List<Node> children`  rather than `Node[] children` which allows adding more elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had have a similar task and I use this code, I hope can help you, maybe you can adapt it.

```
public void CargarBaseDatos() {

    String linea = "";
    String[] atr = new String[18];
    int finCabecera = 0;
    this.bbdd = new ArrayList<Instances>();
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(bbddComplete));
        //bf.write(colect.toString());
        linea = bf.readLine();
        int cabe = 0;
        while (linea != null) {

            if (finCabecera == 1) {
                atr = linea.split(",");
                this.cargaInstancia(atr);
            } else if (linea.equals("@data")) {
                finCabecera = 1;
            } else if ((finCabecera == 0)) {
                if (linea.contains("@attribute")) {
                    this.cabeceraATR[cabe] = linea;
                    cabe++;
                } else {
                    cabecera.append(linea + "\n");
                }
            }
            linea = bf.readLine();
        }
        bf.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Bloque catch generado autom�ticamente
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is a part of file that I read.

> %Base de infecciosos con formato .arff para weka
>
> @relation prueba
>
> @attribute sexo {true,false} @attribute Edad INTEGER @attribute Tot
> INTEGER
>
> @data
>
> false,55,76,9,70,28,true,true,true,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false
> false,25,75,75,85,16,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false
> true,23,80,60,55,29,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false
> true,19,85,85,60,25,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false
> false,51,45,30,70,21,true,true,false,true,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,false